# HTML seems to be ignoring PHP commands?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm a complete newbie when it comes to HTML, I've never needed to do any webpage stuff before so apologies if I'm being a simpleton.

I have a high score table for an iOS app, and I want to display it on the website for the app as well. The leaderboard is working fine in the app using PHP and mySQL, but when I try to access the database using PHP inside an HTML file it doesn't seem to pay any attention to the logic of the PHP (i.e. if I have an if/else statement, it will run both even cases).

Here is a simplified version of my code, if connection to the database is successful then the first column in the table header will say "success", otherwise it will say "failure".

```
<body>

<table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">

<?php
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
{
    <tr>
    <th>Failure</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
    </tr>
}
else
{
    <tr>
    <th>Success</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
    </tr>
}

?>

</table>
</body>
```

Can anyone see what has been done incorrectly here? I assumed that the if/else would work as normal, but instead I get both rows inserted into the table, "failure" and "success".

Edit:
I have also tried using echo ""; etc, but not sure which way is correct as they both give me the same error where it ignores the PHP.

Comment: Please post some real code - if you want us to check your PHP logic, why strip stuff out of it?

Comment: You shouldn't use php in an html file. It should be in a php file.

Comment: @DvirAzulay, the poster has made a commendable and valid effort to make a sscce: http://sscce.org/ We really don't need to see all of their code if this example demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks Spender, that's exactly why it's short.

Comment: Oh! @spender and @TheBestBigAl, sorry, turns out to be I understood his question wrong. I thought that the code compiled, but somehow ended up showing both the `if` and the `else` blocks on the screen, which lead me to believe some code is missing, because that code has parse errors. Thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check extension of your file. It need to be filename.php
You need a server to launch php code
You can use echo heredoc like here

```
<body>

<table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">

<?php
if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
{
echo <<<_END
<tr>
<th>Failure</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
</tr>
_END
}
else
{
echo <<<_END
<tr>
<th>Success</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
</tr>
_END
}
?>
</table>
</body>
```

That seems to be working

Comment: Spot on. I'm being an idiot today and was using an HTML extension. I'll mark as complete in a few minutes

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to

```
    <table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">

    <?php
    if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    {
?>
        <tr>
        <th>Failure</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
        </tr>
  <?php
   }
    else
    {
  ?>
        <tr>
        <th>Success</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
        </tr>
<?php
    }

    ?>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you need to put your HTML tags in the `echo` command like this

```
echo '<tr>
      <th>Failure</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th>         <th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
      </tr>';
```

this should work

Comment: Edited after posting to say I'd tried that too, problem has now been solved though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Between `<?php` and `?>` is just PHP code. It is treating you HTML as PHP.

Either

1. Use `echo`
2. put `?>` before the HTML and `<?php>` after (i.e. stop and start PHP processing)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    <body>

    <table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">

    <?php
    if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <th>Failure</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
    else
    {
?>
        <tr>
        <th>Success</th><th>Player</th><th>Points</th><th>Played</th><th>Wins</th><th>Draws</th><th>Losses</th>
        </tr>
     <?php } ?>

    </table>
    </body>
```